# recursive implementation of sum to target Python

Tags: python, recursion, combinations, combinatorics

I have the following method that, given a target integer, generates all ways to create that integer from an ordered row of integers, subject to the condition that the column index (starting from one) multiplied by the number sums to the target for each row.

Below is some code that achieves this.

```
target = 7
for x in range(math.floor(target/4)+1):
    for f in range(math.floor((target-4)/3)+1):
        for t in range(math.floor((target-4*x-3*f)/2)+1):
            s = target - 2*t - 3*f - 4*x
            print(s,t,f,x)

7 0 0 0
5 1 0 0
3 2 0 0
1 3 0 0
4 0 1 0
2 1 1 0
0 2 1 0
3 0 0 1
1 1 0 1
0 0 1 1
```

Notice that all rows sum to `target=7`, i.e. take the bottom row `0*1 + 0*2 + 1*3 + 1*4=7`.

In the general case, I do not know the number of columns that I require. For instance, I might simply have

```
target = 7
for t in range(math.floor(target/2)+1):
    s = target - 2*t
    print(s,t)
```

or indeed, many more `for` loops.

How can I generalise this, most likely based on a recursive solution, so that the number of columns is a parameter?

Comment: Clearly, you can never have more than `target` columns.

Comment: Good observation!  `target` will be swept from `range(0,target_max)` which could be large, however.

Comment: Rather than recursing, there's probably something in `itertools` that you can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a recursive solution.  You just run through the options for the last column, then fetch the combinations for whatever's leftover using the remaining columns.

```
def gencombos( target, column ):
    if column == 1:
        yield [target]
    else:
        for i in range( 0, target//column+1 ):
            for row in gencombos( target-i*column, column-1 ):
                yield row+[i]

for row in gencombos( 7, 4 ):
    print(row)
```

Output:

```
[7, 0, 0, 0]
[5, 1, 0, 0]
[3, 2, 0, 0]
[1, 3, 0, 0]
[4, 0, 1, 0]
[2, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 2, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 2, 0]
[3, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 1]
```

You can change it the call to (7,6) to see the difference.

Comment: Wow, I have been struggling with that all day!  Impressive solution. What does the // do in the range?

Comment: Integer division.  `a//b` is the same as `math.floor(a/b)`.